# Get Url Parameters In Django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I want to get current transaction id in url. it should be like this

> www.example.com/final_result/53432e1dd34b3

.

I wrote the below codes, but after successful payment, I'm redirected to Page 404.

> (www.example.com/final_result//)

Views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def pay_notif(request, v_transaction_id):
    if request.method=='POST':
        v_transaction_id=request.POST.get('transaction_id')
        endpoint='https://testpay.com/?v_transaction_id={0}&type=json'
        req=endpoint.format(v_transaction_id)
        last_result=urlopen(req).read()
        if 'Approved' in last_result:
            session=Pay.objects.filter(session=request.session.session_key).latest('id')
        else:
            return HttpResponse(status=204)
    return render_to_response('final.html',{'session':session},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Urls.py

```
url(r'^final_result/(?P<v_transaction_id>[-A-Za-z0-9_]+)/$', 'digiapp.views.pay_notif', name="pay_notif"),
```

Template:

```
<input type='hidden' name='v_merchant_id' value='{{newpayy.v_merchant_id}}' />
<input type='hidden' name='item_1' value='{{ newpayy.esell.up_name }}' />
<input type='hidden' name='description_1' value='{{ newpayy.esell.up_description }}' />
<input type='hidden' name='price_1' value='{{ newpayy.esell.up_price }}' />

#page to be redirected to after successful payment
 <input type='hidden' name='success_url'  value='http://127.0.0.1:8000/final_result/{{newpayy.v_transaction_id}}/' />
```

How can I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the call to render_to_response, you pass a context with a single key "session" FWIW it will break on a GET request since the name 'session' is only defined in your view for a POST request). In the template you are refering to name "newpayy", which obviously doesn't exist. As a side note you should use the `{% url %}` template tag instead of hardcoding your url.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did this: value="{% url pay_notif v_transaction_id %}" but am getting Reverse error.Reverse for 'pay_notif' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

Comment: Looks like you didn't even read the first (and most important) part of the answer. Please do yourself a favour and read the FineManual for the part about templates and context : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/api/#rendering-a-context - this will save you quite a lot of pain.

Comment: Actually I did. The 'newpayy' takes another view. And the view is responsible for POST request, whereby users will input their email, phone num. adding "v_transaction_id' in the def confam_pay(request):
    return render_to_response('confam_pay.html',{'newpayy':Pay.objects.filter().latest('id')},context_instance=RequestContext(request)) will raise an error that's why I'm trying to figure out how to go about this.

Comment: If you update your code please edit / update your post accordingly - very few of us have mind-reading abilities, you know ? But anyway: if you don't explicitely set some name in a context, the template cannot access this name neither. I don't see any "v_transaction_id" key in any of the snippets you posted.